# Can i add a row number in object list while mapping with automapper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

I want to add row number in object list.
here's the they i do it now but there must be  better way

**Profile for mapping**

```
public class VendorEnquiryDM_TO_VM : Profile
{
    public VendorEnquiryDM_TO_VM()
    {
        CreateMap<VENDORENQUIRY, VendorEnquiryVM>();
    }
}
public class VendorEnquiryVM_TO_DM : Profile
{
    public VendorEnquiryVM_TO_DM()
    {
        CreateMap<VENDOR_ENQUIRY, VendorEnquiryVM>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

**Register profile**

```
cfg.AddProfile<VendorEnquiryDM_TO_VM>();
cfg.AddProfile<VendorEnquiryVM_TO_DM>();
```

**This is how I add sno.**

```
alldata = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Vendor_EnquiryVM>>(objDAO.getVendorEnquiry());
var _roles = alldata.Select((t, index) => new Vendor_EnquiryVM
{
    sno = index + 1,
    CONTACT_NO=t.CONTACT_NO,
    DATE=t.DATE,
    EMAIL=t.EMAIL,
    id=t.id, 
    FIRST_NAME=t.FIRST_NAME,
    wer=t.wer,
    asdf=t.asdf
});
```

Due to just one serial no. I need to assign all properties and this is somewhat fraustrating to me for large model, please suggest me better way of doing this.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a static Id and when you create the class, increment it by one

here how your class code should look like

```
public class Test
{
    private static int mId = 0;

    public Test()
    {
        mId = mId +1;
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get{ return mId;}
    }
}
```

[Here a demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/R52FHd)

in order to use the same idea with collections like `List`, I applied some modifications and here what you can do

```
public class Test
{
    private static int mIndex = 0; // this parameter will be incremented for each new Test
    private int mId =0; // this parameter will hold the last incremented value

    public Test()
    {
        mId = ++mIndex; // mIndex++ if you want to start with 0
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get{ return mId;}
    }
}
```

[Demo with lists](https://dotnetfiddle.net/x7ohMR)

hope this will help you

Comment: will it return ItemIndex+1 in a collection of test class object?

Comment: @BrBhardwaj yes, check the demo

Comment: where is your problem in this solution exactly?

Comment: @BrBhardwaj I modified the solution to work with collections based on your first comment

Comment: needed 15 reputation points to mark as answer which i dont have ,thanks btw.

Comment: I wish can accept this as answer, Thanks @Monah that is work perfectly. I gave point to question too, So I hope Br Bhardwaj can accept this as answer.